# How to use yesod per-request caching?

Tags: haskell, caching, yesod

I'm trying to use the `cached` function to prevent multiple db queries in different widgets and handlers:

```
newtype CachedBobId key
    = CachedBobId { unCachedBobId :: key }
    deriving Typeable

getBob' :: Handler BobId
getBob' = do
    uncle <- runInputGet $ ireq textField "bobsuncle"
    (Entity bob _) <- runDB $ getBy404 $ UniqueBob uncle
    return bob

getBob :: Handler BobId
getBob = do
    a <- getBob'
    let b = return $ CachedBobId a
    c <- cached b
    return $ unCachedBobId c
```

And in a widget somewhere:

```
renderDerp :: Widget
renderDerp = do
    --these are used in the shakespeare files
    lolBob <- handlerToWidget $ getBob
    nutherBob <- handlerToWidget $ getBob
    $(widgetFile "test")
```

This compiles but the query to get the ID still runs multiple times.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to only get bob once and use him in every handler and widget?

Comment: Didn't really read code inside the question (since I had a problem with `cached` too). Someone is going to get really easy 200 points.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty new to Yesod, but I think you just need to tweak `getBob`

```
getBob :: Handler BobId
getBob = unCachedBobId <$> cached (CachedBobId <$> getBob')
```

The problem is that your current `getBob` function starts its `do` block with `a <- getBob'`. Remember that a `do` block sequences monadic actions, so you actually end up calling `getBob'` first thing every time `getBob` is called. In an ironic twist, after you've done this, you create a cached version of a handler which returns what you just got from `getBob'`, but end up querying that cached version exactly once (right afterwards with `c <- cached b`), then it just falls out of scope and the garbage collector gets it.

In the solution I present above, you wrap whatever `getBob'` gives you in `CachedBobId`. Then, you pass that handler `CachedBobId <$> getBob' :: Handler (CachedBobId BobId)`, to `cached`, which gives you back another handler `cached (CachedBobId <$> getBob')` of the same type, but with caching. Finally, you extract whatever the cached handler gives you to get back a `Handler BobId`.